# Security Manager Having Issue with Java 17 and spring boot runnable jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, java-17

I am migrating a project from Java-8 and spring boot 2.x to Java 17 and Spring boot 3.x
The project use Security Manager for some of internal requirements and can't be removed as of now.
When the project is started using intellij i.e.

`java -classpath <all local classes>;<all dependencies> <main class>`

It works fine but if the final executable jar is used then a lot of class not found exception occurs for logger, ignite etc. Also if security manager is turned off errors doesn't come

`java -jar <executable jar>`

code used to enable custom security manager

```
    log.warn("Enabling PlatformSecurityManager");
    Policy policy = Policy.getPolicy();
    PermissionCollection perm = policy.getPermissions(new CodeSource(null, (Certificate[]) null));
    boolean canReplaceSecurityManager = perm.implies(new RuntimePermission("setSecurityManager"));
    if (System.getSecurityManager() != null && !canReplaceSecurityManager) {
      //we have to do the check like this because it will be from a different classloader
      if (!(System.getSecurityManager().getClass().getName().equals(PlatformSecurityManager.class.getName()))) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
            "You have started the JVM with a security manager that doesn't allow me to set a new one!");
      }
      //else another platform application has specified the security manager... so we should be ok
    } else {
      if (System.getProperty("java.security.policy") == null) {
        log.warn("java.security.policy Not found");
        //load up allow all policy
        log.info("Enabling AllPermission for the platform security manager");
        PlatformSecurityPolicy platformPolicy = new PlatformSecurityPolicy();
        platformPolicy.addPermission(new AllPermission());
        Policy.setPolicy(platformPolicy);
      }

      log.warn("Enabled PlatformSecurityManager");
      System.setSecurityManager(new PlatformSecurityManager(false));
    }
```

Please add comment if any additional info is needed.
Any lead/help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per below article, it is a bug in spring boot with Java 11 +
Although they have fixed it is spring 2.3+ but same is not frontported to 3.x so after applying below workaround it worked for me

`-Dsun.misc.URLClassPath.disableJarChecking=true`

Reference Article

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/25538